# EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

есть вот такой код:

```
import time
import subprocess
import pyttsx3
from waiter import run
engine = pyttsx3.init()
ru_voice_id = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_RU-RU_IRINA_11.0"
engine.setProperty('voice', ru_voice_id)
print('begin')
engine.say('добро пожаловать, создатель')
engine.say('Жду ваших указаний!')
engine.runAndWait()
choice = input()
if choice == 'run':
    run()
proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```

Он выдаёт ошибку:

> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

```
begin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assistant.py", line 13, in <module>
    choice = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

И я не понимаю, почему, и как её решить.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, еще я вызываю скрипт с помощью другого скрипта в автозагрузке через командную строку.

Answer (score 1):

ТС [написал в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1004889/#comment1702729_1004889):

> еще я вызываю скрипт с помощью другого скрипта

Если как-то так вызывать, то получите ошибку:

```
$ echo -n | python3 -c "input()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

`echo -n | script` вызывает скрипт в субпроцессе ничего не передавая на его стандартный ввод. Eсли вызываемый скрипт пытается читать данные, то вызывающий скрипт должен их писать.